# Rate Limit Xen DomU Network Traffic

Tags: networking, xen, rate-limiting, domu

Is there a solid way to rate limit Xen DomU Network I/O Traffic? I found an answer on here using tc but I get this error:

Object "qdisk" is unknown, try "tc help".

I guess a solution to either of these problems would be excellent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's spelled `qdisc`, not `qdisk`.

Comment: Hah, wow. Go figure my bad spelling would be my demise. That clears things up a bit. Thanks a bunch. :)